# How to get the content of file with Solr?

Tags: json, curl, solr

Is it possible get all content of file with Solr when I have some match in my query?

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=word"
```

I have this JSON as return, I'm thinking if here I can receive the content of the file, too.

```js
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":17,
    "params":{
      "q":"word",
      "indent":"true",
      "wt":"json"}
    },
    "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"maxScore":0.17318419,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"/file.txt",
        "stream_size":[780],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "stream_content_type":["text/plain"],
        "content_encoding":["UTF-8"],
        "resourcename":["/file.txt"],
        "content_type":["text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],
        "_version_":1525636445177380864},
      }
    ]
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Has the content of the file been indexed? How is the schema.xml?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't create my schema.xml. I'm using the cloud Solr and see only this documents: `configoverlay.json, currency.xml, elevate.xml, lang/, params.json, protwords.txt, solrconfig.xml, stopwords.txt, synonyms.txt`. How should be the `schema.xml` to be able to see the content of the file?

Comment: Default collection in solr uses managed schema which updates automatically when a new filed is added. To answer to your question on storing the file in SOLR; I have not seen that so far. What we do is index the meta data of the file and store the url/directory in solr as a stored field and fetch it from the remote location when we get a hit

Comment: @AneeshMonN I'm doing this. I get the directory with the `resourcename`, but it seems so stranger.

Comment: SOLR helps you retrieve results based on query, not sure on storing the file as a whole.